# Is it defined to write to the same buffer from different kernels?

Tags: opencl

I have OpenCL 1.1, one device, out of order execution command queue, 
and want that multiple kernels output their results into one buffer to different, not overlapped, arbitrary, regions.
Is it possible?

```
cl::CommandQueue commandQueue(context, CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE);

cl::Buffer buf_as(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, data_size, &as[0]);
cl::Buffer buf_bs(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, data_size, &bs[0]);

cl::Buffer buf_rs(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, data_size, NULL);

cl::Kernel kernel(program, "dist");

kernel.setArg(0, buf_as);
kernel.setArg(1, buf_bs);

int const N = 4;
int const d = data_size / N;
std::vector<cl::Event> events(N);

for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    int const beg = d * i;
    int const len = d;

    kernel_leaf.setArg(2, beg);
    kernel_leaf.setArg(3, len);

    commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, NULL, cl::NDRange(block_size_x), cl::NDRange(block_size_x), NULL, &events[i]);
}

commandQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(buf_rs, CL_FALSE, 0, data_size, &rs[0], &events, NULL);

commandQueue.finish();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to give an official committee response to this. We realise the specification is ambiguous and have made modifications to rectify this.

This is **not** guaranteed under OpenCL 1.x or indeed 2.0 rules. cl_mem objects are only guaranteed to be consistent at synchronization points, even when processed only on a single device and even when used by OpenCL 2.0 kernels using *memory_scope_device*.

Multiple child kernels of an OpenCL 2.0 parent kernel can share the parent's cl_mem objects at device scope.

Coarse-grained SVM objects can be shared at device scope between multiple kernels, as long as the memory locations written to are not overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

The writes should work fine if the global memory addresses are non-overlapping as you have described. Just make sure both kernels are finished before reading the results back to the host.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct according to the specification, though it may be true of actual implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is defined. Although you say you are writing to non-overlapping regions at the software level, it is not guaranteed that at the hardware level the accesses won't map onto same cache lines - in which case you'll have multiple modified versions flying around.

Comment: Multiple cache lines shouldn't be an issue, hardware generally uses dirty masks fine and handles this. Virtual memory mapping could become an issue, however. Coarse grained SVM is required to behave correctly. Even in OpenCL 2.0 cl_mem objects are not required to allow multiple writers on the same device to the same buffer.

Comment: dirty masks are less common than you think, due to the hardware overhead (e.g, byte-granularity dirty mask adds a minimum of 12% to cache die area). Moreover, the question is about whether OCL spec guarantees it to be ok, which it doesn't.